# datepicker and textfields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, datepicker

I am new to ios development and need to know how to set up two text fields which get dates from date pickers. Here's the code:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DatePickerForTermins : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    //NSDate *frmDate;
    UIActionSheet *dateSheet;
    UIActionSheet *dateSheet2;





}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fromDateTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *toDateTextField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *chosenFromDateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *chosenToDateLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDate *frmDate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDate *toDate;

-(void)setDateFRM;
-(void)dismissDateSet;
-(void)cancelDateSet;
-(void)setDateTO;
-(void)dismissDateSet2;
-(void)cancelDateSet2;
@end
```

and .m file:

```
#import "DatePickerForTermins.h"

@interface DatePickerForTermins ()

@end

@implementation DatePickerForTermins
@synthesize fromDateTextField;
@synthesize chosenFromDateLabel;
@synthesize frmDate;
@synthesize chosenToDateLabel;
@synthesize toDateTextField;
@synthesize toDate;




- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)setDateFRM
{

    dateSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [dateSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleDefault];

    CGRect pickerFrame=CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0);
    UIDatePicker *frmDatePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [frmDatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    [dateSheet addSubview:frmDatePicker];
    UIToolbar *controlToolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, dateSheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];

    [controlToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [controlToolBar sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem *spacer=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];


    UIBarButtonItem *setButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Set Date" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDateSet)];


    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelDateSet)];



    [controlToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer,cancelButton,setButton, nil]animated:NO];

    [dateSheet addSubview:controlToolBar];

    [dateSheet showInView:self.view];

    [dateSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 425)];

}
-(void)setDateTO
{

    dateSheet2=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [dateSheet2 setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleDefault];

    CGRect pickerFrame=CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0);
    UIDatePicker *frmDatePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [frmDatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    [dateSheet2 addSubview:frmDatePicker];
    UIToolbar *controlToolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, dateSheet2.bounds.size.width, 44)];

    [controlToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [controlToolBar sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem *spacer=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];


    UIBarButtonItem *setButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Set Date" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDateSet2)];


    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelDateSet2)];



    [controlToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer,cancelButton,setButton, nil]animated:NO];

    [dateSheet2 addSubview:controlToolBar];

    [dateSheet2 showInView:self.view];

    [dateSheet2 setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 425)];

}
-(void)cancelDateSet
{
    [dateSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

}
-(void)cancelDateSet2
{
    [dateSheet2 dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

}

-(void)dismissDateSet
{
    NSArray *listOfSubviews=[dateSheet subviews];
    for (NSString *sre in listOfSubviews) {
        NSLog(@"Lista Sub:%@",sre);
    }


    for (UIView *subView in listOfSubviews) {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIDatePicker class]]){

            self.frmDate=[(UIDatePicker*)subView date];

        }
    }
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    [fromDateTextField setText:[dateFormater stringFromDate:self.frmDate]];


    //    NSCalendar *calendar=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    //    unsigned unitFlags= NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    //    NSDateComponents

    NSString *outputStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"From Datum je:%@",self.frmDate];



    [self.chosenFromDateLabel setText:outputStr];


    [dateSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];



}

-(void)dismissDateSet2
{
    NSArray *listOfSubviews=[dateSheet2 subviews];
    for (NSString *sre in listOfSubviews) {
        NSLog(@"Lista Sub2:%@",sre);
    }

    for (UIView *subView in listOfSubviews) {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIDatePicker class]]){

            self.toDate=[(UIDatePicker*)subView date];

    }
}
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    [toDateTextField setText:[dateFormater stringFromDate:self.toDate]];


//    NSCalendar *calendar=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
//    unsigned unitFlags= NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
//    NSDateComponents 

    NSString *outputStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"From Datum je:%@",self.frmDate];



    [self.chosenToDateLabel setText:outputStr];


    [dateSheet2 dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];



}




-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{


        [self setDateFRM];
        return NO;





}

@end
```

The other text field just gives the plain keyboard instead of datepicker. Anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use "addTarget" to get a message when the dates was changed.

Example:

```
[rmDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged|;
 ...

-(void) datePickerValueChanged:(id) sender {
   UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)sender;
   NSDate dateFromPicker = picker.date;
   fromDateTextField.text = [dateFromPicker description];
}
```

More infos: [Target-Action in UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you just tell me the following:
I'm not sure I understand what you want to do this? and how will it help me since I already set the date in the top method?