# How to get value from two textFields?

Tags: ios, ios6, datepicker, textfield

I have two textFields and I have replaced default tap behavior from keyboard to DatePicker

```
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)_editStartDate.inputView;
    _editStartDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];

    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];       
    [_editStartDate setInputView:datePicker];
...
}
```

This code create datepicker instead of keyboard and update textField with name editStartDate, but I have 2nd textField with name editEndDate and I don't know how to get value in it too.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: see this question and see if it'll help. it might not give you the definitive answer but it may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433167/datepicker-and-textfields

Comment: so you want to set start and end date from single datePicker?

Comment: I have 2 textFields and I want to have DatePicker instead of default keyboard on each of them. After I want to select date and get this date in textField. In the 1st field if I clicked to the 1st textField or in the 2nd if I clicked to the 2nd textField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{

    if([_editStartDate isFirstResponder]){
        UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)_editStartDate.inputView;
        _editStartDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
    }
    if([_editEndDate isFirstResponder]){
        UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)_editEndDate.inputView;
        _editEndDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thx, but I make a little error,
not     [self setInputView:datePicker];
right option:     [_editStartDate setInputView:datePicker];